# Creating pages dynamically in PDFbox - Java for Android

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

I coded an app that stores texts in Room db and the user can create a pdf file contains selected texts retrieved from the db. I'm using PDFbox for creating the pdf files but PDFbox doesn't create new pages automatically as needed. I want the app to create pages in a given pdf file dynamically.
Here is my code:

```
       public void writeDataIntoFile() {

        if (adapter.getItemCount()> 0) {
            String filePath = createFile();
            Log.d("saving pdf", filePath);

            PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getApplicationContext());
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;



            document.addPage(page);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream;

            try {
                // Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

                contentStream.beginText();

                contentStream.setStrokingColor(44, 61, 79);
                contentStream.setFont(font, 18);
                contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                showProgressBar();
                executor.execute(() -> {

                    try { //Background work here - function goes here

                        //TODO I need to add functions to return words by category
                    
                        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 770);

                        contentStream.showText("Category: " + categoryName);

                        contentStream.newLine();
                        contentStream.newLine();


                        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
                       contentStream.setFont(font, 12);

                        for (Word word : adapter.getCurrentList()) {


                            showMultiLineText(word.getWord() + ": "
                                    + word.getTranslation(),
                                    550,
                                    contentStream,font,
                                    12);

                            contentStream.newLine();
                            count++;



                        }
                        contentStream.endText();
                        contentStream.close();

                        document.save(filePath);
                        saved = true;
                        document.close();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("error", String.valueOf(e));
                    }


                    handler.post(() -> {
                        //UI Thread work here - progress bar goes here
                        hideProgressBar();
                        openingPDF(filePath);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "the file has been saved in /Download/MemorizeWords", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    });


                });

                executor.shutdown();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("error", String.valueOf(e));

            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This category has no words!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Here is a function checks whether text longer than page width and splits texts if needed:

````
private void showMultiLineText(String text, int allowedWidth, PDPageContentStream contentStream,
                                          PDFont font,
                                          int fontSize) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = "";
        // split the text on spaces
        String[] words = text.split(" ");
        for(String word : words) {
            if(!line.isEmpty()) {
                line += " ";
            }
            // check if adding the word to the line surpasses the width of the page
            int size = (int) (fontSize * font.getStringWidth(line + word) / 1000);
            if(size > allowedWidth) {
                // if line + word surpasses the width of the page, add the line without the current word
                lines.add(line);
                // start new line with the current word
                line = word;
            } else {
                // if line + word fits the page width, add the current word to the line
                line += word;
            }
        }
        lines.add(line);
        for(String ln : lines) {
            count = lines.size();
            contentStream.showText(ln);
            contentStream.newLine();
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Essentially you have to keep track of how many lines have been drawn and whether a new page has to be started yourself. Alternatively there are some packages on top of PDFBox that do that for you. Which way do you want to go?

Comment: I prefer using packages.